# Calling Oracle Query Using PHP Function with constructor

Tags: javascript, php, sql, oracle

I dont know where my mistake is but i want to store an oracle query inside a function and return that function inside an array.

JobDrop.php

```
class JobDrop {
    private $jobSql = "SELECT VMI.PROJECT_NO JOB FROM VW_MTO_INFO VMI ORDER BY VMI.PROJECT_NO ASC";

    function _construct($jobSql){
        $this->jobSql = $jobSql;
    }

    function JobDropdown($conn){
        $jobParse = oci_parse($conn, $this->jobSql);
        $jobExcErr = oci_execute($jobParse);

        if (!$jobExcErr){
            $e = oci_error($jobParse);
                print htmlentities($e['message']);
                print "\n<pre>\n";
                print htmlentities($e['sqltext']);
                printf("\n%".($e['offset']+1)."s", "^");
                print  "\n</pre>\n";
        } else {

            $res = array();
            while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($jobParse)){
                $res[] = $row;
            } 
            $listVendor = json_encode($res, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

            return $listVendor;
        }


}
    }
```

and in test.php

```
include './job_drop.php';
require_once('../../lib/dbinfo.inc.php');
$conn = oci_connect(ORA_CON_UN, ORA_CON_PW, ORA_CON_DB);


$jobdrop = new JobDrop();

$jobdrop->JobDropdown($conn);
var_dump($jobdrop);
```

but it doesnt show the array inside the browser. it shows the query string instead,

```
object(JobDrop)#1 (1) { ["jobSql":"JobDrop":private]=> string(74) "SELECT VMI.PROJECT_NO JOB FROM VW_MTO_INFO VMI ORDER BY VMI.PROJECT_NO ASC" }
```

Please help me where I am doing wrong here

Comment: Are you saying you want to save the results of the query in the JobDrop class? As you have it now, you are not capturing the return value of JobDropdown function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the array, do:

```
$res = $jobdrop->JobDropdown($conn);
var_dump($res);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @IanKemp: the author's post identifies `but it doesnt show the array inside the browser. it shows the query string instead` as the proximate issue for which help is being requested.  My answer addresses that.